# Trouble Installing "mobius-client-js"

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

Keep failing to install mobius-client-js"

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>yarn add @mobius-network/mobius-client-js
yarn add v1.12.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error @mobius-network/mobius-client-js@0.5.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=4 <=9". Got "10.14.1"
error Found incompatible module
```

Per Yarn's docs, you can use the following methods to add:

You can also specify packages from different locations:

> `yarn add package-name` installs the package from the npm registry
>   unless you have specified another one in your package.json.
>
> `yarn add file:/path/to/local/folder` installs a package that is on
>   your local file system. This is useful to test out other packages of
>   yours that haven’t been published to the registry.
>
> `yarn add file:/path/to/local/tarball.tgz` installs a package from a
>   gzipped tarball which could be used to share a package before
>   publishing it.
>
> `yarn add <git remote url>` installs a package from a remote git
>   repository.
>
> `yarn add <git remote url>#<branch/commit/tag>` installs a package from
>   a remote git repository at specific git branch, git commit or git tag.
>
> `yarn add https://my-project.org/package.tgz` installs a package from a
>   remote gzipped tarball.

None are working... any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your error message:

```
The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=4 <=9". Got "10.14.1"
```

It looks like you are running **NodeJS 10.14.1**, but the `mobius-client` requires a NodeJS version between **4** and **9**. You should either check if there's a compatible version of this library or use something like `nvm` to switch to a previous version of node.

Comment: I can't vote your comment up as my reputation is to low; with that said, I had already started down that road, and running into additional problems... Trying to install nvm on Windows is seemingly installed, but unrecognized still. 

The error: when running install:

'nvm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: The error you are running into currently looks like the nvm command is not in your executable path. You raise an issue the maintainers on Github, or try to install node 9 manually. But that would be unrelated to this question, and it would be hard to support through comments. The best would be to post a new question related to `nvm`.

Comment: how to use nvm?